# How to pick up the database name and table name from the URL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, url

I am new to PHP.
I need a help regarding the methods of extracting DB name and table name from the given URL name.
For example, let's say, I have an URL like the one below:

/test.php?db=...&table=.../

How to extract the DB name and table name from this URL using PHP and use the result for other query purposes.

Comment: `parse_url` and `parse_str()` will help you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: I know, you are just getting started and figure out the basics. But you should know that there are are lot of security aspects to consider when you pass a user entry (from the URL) into your database. Maybe start reading here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to parse an existing URL for it's parameters:

parse_url() and parse_str() will help you strip the components of the url.  You will primarily be looking at the following

```
$elements = parse_url($url);
$kvps = $elements->query;
$db = parse_str($kvps['db']);
$table = parse_str($kvps['table']);
```

But, if you mean how to GET variables from the current page before render:

```
<?php

$dbname = $_GET['db'];
$tablename = $_GET['table'];

?>
```

And yea, there are major security risks involved in opening up 'direct' access to your database this way.  Best to obfuscate / encapsulate / wrap your functions in tasks like `index.php&addUser=tim` instead of `index.php&insert=tim&db=boofar&table=users&dbuser=root&dbpassword=secure`.

If you're just learning, what you're doing is fine, as long as you realize why it's wrong.  If you're coding for production, you really need an alternate solution.

Comment: Similar to that..but I have to get the values from URL.How to do that?

Comment: Use parse_url() as @Pekka has suggested.

Comment: `$_GET` *are* the values from the URL query string.

Comment: @Geoist feel free to incorporate `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` into your answer... people too lazy to answer, adding a comment instead, forfeit their rights :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass variables or data to another page.

GET (via the URL)
and
POST (usually a form submission)

You can alway get via
$_GET
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

or

$_POST
http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php